# Why 'object.size' not accepting 'units' argument

Tags: r, built-in

Apparently 'object.size' function accepting only one argument(i.e., object), but not 'units' or any other arguments. How can I tackle it?

here is what happens if I try it anyway:

```
object.size(averageBySubAct, units = "Mb")

Error in object.size(averageBySubAct, units = "Mb") : 
  unused argument (units = "Mb")
```

Comment: `print(object.size(x), units = "MB")` or `pryr::object_size(x)
`

Comment: Or `format(object.size(x), units = "Mb")`.  It's all right there at the top of `help(object.size)`

Comment: Downvoting this is unreasonable, it's a very legitimate new-user question: I've been using R for 7 years now and still trip over this. the confusion is introduced by `object.size()`'s manpage prominently referencing a units argument, without clearly stating that that refers to the associated S3 `print/format` methods, not `object.size()` itself. Like many of us, I wrote a custom fn to get the formatted object-size (before `pryr::object_size` ever existed).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
?object.size
```

this gives

```
object.size(x)

## S3 method for class 'object_size'
format(x, units = "b", ...)
## S3 method for class 'object_size'
print(x, quote = FALSE, units = "b", ...)
```

notice that `object.size()`takes one argument, `x`. However, we can print the result of `object.size(x)` and then use the `units` argument (as mentioned in the comments)

```
print(object.size(c(5,6,1)), units="Mb")
# 0 Mb
```

Comment: `format` is probably preferable as the results are saved as displayed, e.g. compare `form <- format(object.size(x),units="Mb")` and `prnt <- print(object.size(x),units="Mb")` and then `prnt;form;`